# Use pseudo element's content attribute to change img

Tags: css, image, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make a twinkling effect using animation and replacing image. And here's my code, please tell me where I go wrong.

HTML code

```
<img class="lantern red" src="images/lantern.png">
```

CSS code

```
.lantern::before { 
    content: url("images/lantern_twinkless.png"); position: absolute; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100% 
}
```

Comment: You can't attach :pseudo-element to `img` element.

Comment: Where is the animation itself?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Is there any possible way to change image dynamically?

Comment: @hayley - Yes there is. Its a hacky way though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you [can not apply pseudo](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) elements on images the workaround for this is to use the figure tag

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of
>   :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This
>   will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

```css
figure{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto
}

figure:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green
}
```

```html
<figure>
</figure>
```

Comment: If you want to keep browser support, use a div with a class and background images.